# using string concatenation display 0 instead of null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a form which contains textboxes,"search" button. when user enter the values and click on the button I have to display the search details. and
I have to display no.of searchresults:
no.of search results i have obtained by using array.length; I want to use this value in another view page.so I put this value in the `sessionStorage.setItem("getCount",len);`
I am concatinating this value in the other view page like:

`Search Results:" + sessionStorage.getItem('getCount') + "`

I am getting the number of search results when user enters the value in the form.
but when user enter no values in the form then at the searchresults: it is displaying "null". but i want to display "0" insted of null.
how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this work. The simplest is to check if `sessionStorage.getItem('getCount')` is null and if is null you can return 0.

This is the code:

`Search Results:" + sessionStorage.getItem('getCount') == null ? "0" : sessionStorage.getItem('getCount')`

Comment: hi,I gave like this                                             Search Results:" + sessionStorage.getItem('getCount') == null ? "0":sessionStorage.getItem('getCount')+"                                It is displaying  only "null" in this place